# How to pass a string parameter to a Java method in a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am not able to call the Java function inside JavaScript. I guess ,I am doing it wrong when I am passing paramters like Var to a string method. Please give me your suggestions.

```
function calculateTotalAmount()
{

    var formFldAreaCode = eval("document.AccountsSummaryListing.<%=SWPAppConstants.AREA_CODE%>");   
    alert("area code "+formFldAreaCode.value);
    var formFldExchange = eval("document.AccountsSummaryListing.<%=SWPAppConstants.EXCHANGE%>");
    alert("formFldExchange "+formFldExchange.value);
    var formFldConnector = eval("document.AccountsSummaryListing.<%=SWPAppConstants.CONNECTOR%>");
    alert("formFldConnector code "+formFldConnector.value);
    var formFldConnectorSuffix = eval("document.AccountsSummaryListing.<%=SWPAppConstants.CONNECTOR_SUFFIX%>");
    alert("formFldConnectorSuffix code "+formFldConnectorSuffix.value);
//getting error here            
     var installmentAmount = '<%=smPage.getFreeDomTerminationFee(formFldAreaCode.value,formFldExchange.value,"'formFldConnector.value,formFldConnectorSuffix.value)%>';

    alert("Alert "+installmentAmount);
}
```

Java Method()
 public String getFreeDomTerminationFee(String areaCode,String exchange,String connector,String suffix) throws Exception
    {

```
    System.out.println("Ramesh areaCode "+areaCode);

m_logMgr.logMessage(LogManager.LOG_EVENT,"AccountsSummaryListing  "+areaCode+"exchange "+exchange+"connector "+connector+" suffix "+suffix, m_FTCuserContext.getCurrentUserId(), 10, 1);        
/*      Connection origConn = m_bussContext.getConnection();
        Connection sosConn = getSOSConnection();
        m_bussContext.setConnection(sosConn);*/ 


    FreedomPlnManager frdmPlnMngr = new FreedomPlnManager(this.m_bussContext, this.m_FTCuserContext);

    String installmentAmount = "0";                     

    FreedomPlnDS freedomPlnDS = frdmPlnMngr.getFreedomPlanDetails(areaCode,exchange ,connector ,suffix);

    //m_bussContext.setConnection(origConn);

    if(freedomPlnDS!= null){
        installmentAmount = freedomPlnDS.getInstallmentAmount();
    }

        m_logMgr.logMessage(LogManager.LOG_EVENT,"AccountsSummaryListing:etfValue =  "+installmentAmount, m_FTCuserContext.getCurrentUserId(), 10, 1);      

    return installmentAmount;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript runs in the browser, Java runs on the server. You need to make an Ajax call from JavaScript to call into the Java app. You can't just simply "call" the Java method directly from JavaScript.